# Why do repeated bind mounts create entries for the source directory?

Tags: linux, mount, bind-mount

Why does a repeated bind mount create multiple entries in `/proc/mounts`?

```
# md -p /mnt/test-mount/{source,target}
# mount --bind /mnt/test-mount/{source,target}
# grep test-mount /proc/mounts 
/dev/sda3 /mnt/test-mount/target ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
# mount --bind /mnt/test-mount/{source,target}
# grep test-mount /proc/mounts 
/dev/sda3 /mnt/test-mount/target ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda3 /mnt/test-mount/target ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda3 /mnt/test-mount/source ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
```

After the first bind mount there was one entry mapping the source
volume to the mountpoint. After the second invocation, we have
one additional entry for the mountpoint plus one for the source
prefix.

Likewise, *findmnt* reports that the source is bind mounted to
itself:

```
# findmnt |grep test-mount
├─/mnt/test-mount/target                       /dev/sda3[/mnt/test-mount/source]                ext4            rw,relatime
│ └─/mnt/test-mount/target                     /dev/sda3[/mnt/test-mount/source]                ext4            rw,relatime
└─/mnt/test-mount/source                       /dev/sda3[/mnt/test-mount/source]                ext4            rw,relatime
```

After another repetition, I end up with *three* entries for the
source, four for the target:

```
# mount --bind /mnt/test-mount/{source,target
# findmnt |grep test-mount
├─/mnt/test-mount/target                       /dev/sda3[/mnt/test-mount/source]                ext4            rw,relatime
│ └─/mnt/test-mount/target                     /dev/sda3[/mnt/test-mount/source]                ext4            rw,relatime
│   └─/mnt/test-mount/target                   /dev/sda3[/mnt/test-mount/source]                ext4            rw,relatime
│     └─/mnt/test-mount/target                 /dev/sda3[/mnt/test-mount/source]                ext4            rw,relatime
└─/mnt/test-mount/source                       /dev/sda3[/mnt/test-mount/source]                ext4            rw,relatime
  └─/mnt/test-mount/source                     /dev/sda3[/mnt/test-mount/source]                ext4            rw,relatime
    └─/mnt/test-mount/source                   /dev/sda3[/mnt/test-mount/source]                ext4            rw,relatime
```

The progression is *1, 3, 7, 15, …*, i. e. *n = 1 + 2^(n-1)*,
causing the number of additional entries to double with each
mount operation.

What’s the reason for this?

Comment: Works as expected for me (one entry for each bind mount, while your output suddenly shows three entries). I don't get those reverse entries out of nowhere. I notice you're using an alias for mkdir, could you be using other aliases that interfere somehow?

Comment: ``alias md='mkdir'``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mount propagation.

This is a specific case of the "mount point explosion problem", which is explained in the "MS_UNBINDABLE example" in [mount_namespaces(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html)

systemd effectively enables mount propagation by default.  For example, this makes it feasible to run a service in a child namespace where `/home` is blocked off, as per the [systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) option `ProtectHome=yes`.  By allowing mounts *and unmounts* to propagate into the child namespace, it lets `eject` continue to work properly in the main namespace, and so on.

Comment: Those are interesting links. With ``--make-unbindable`` I the exponential part is indeed gone. It will still create a new mount entry per invocation but that’s no longer critical.

Comment: @sourcejedi Thanks for pointing that out. Trying it again on a ArchLinux/systemd box, I can reproduce it too. That's scary - do it 10 times in a row and the system almost dies. Not sure it's supposed to work this way...

Comment: Never had such a huge `/proc/mounts` before and reading it with `dd` yields 50KiB/s ... yikes.

Comment: @frostschutz how does *20* times sound? https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/d29216842a85 IOW it's known to work this way for a long time, and the only "fix" that's been applied is to limit the maximum number of mounts before you get into too much trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the link, the `--make-rshared` was the missing piece of the puzzle for me. Still seems braindead somehow, but who am I to judge :-)

Comment: @frostschutz you're in good company :). "The configuration interface for mount propagation is error
prone and pretty much requires the most problematic cases be the default
makine the interfaces very easy to use incorrectly.   Especially for code
that was only tested on systems prior to systemd." -- Eric W Biederman http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2016/07/13/6 .

Comment: Somehow this completely breaks all mount semantics that I'm familiar with. It's a regular --bind mount, not --rbind, yet submounts suddenly propagate anyway, or worse - submounts are outright removed unexpectely (depending whether you do the submount before or after the repeated bind-mount). I don't understand the logic/purpose behind it - if there is any.